.NET MAUI Android - Tabbed Page - indicator color
How can I change the color of the TabbedPage indicator (line) in .NET MAUI (Android)?
I'm developing a .NET MAUI application, and I need to change the color of the selected tab indicator (the underline below the selected tab) in a TabbedPage on Android. I've seen examples of how to do this in Xamarin.Forms, but I couldn't find a straightforward solution for .NET MAUI.
I've tried setting properties like BackgroundColor, BarBackgroundColor, and SelectedTabColor directly on the TabbedPage, but none of these seem to affect the color of the indicator.
My project is complex, so I recreated a simple demo
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiBiometricAppDemo.Views"
            x:Class="MauiBiometricAppDemo.Views.MyTabbedPage"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            BarBackgroundColor="Yellow"
            BarTextColor="Black"
            SelectedTabColor="White"
            UnselectedTabColor="White">
    <local:MainPage />
    <local:NewPage1 />
</TabbedPage>

Resources are in the default state.
The problem is that there is no property that could set the indicator color."

UPDATE: adding other codes
public partial class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}

MainPage
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiBiometricAppDemo.Views.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />


            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me" 
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

NewPage1
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiBiometricAppDemo.Views.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

I didn't add these before, because everything is in default state.

Can you add code showing how you've tried setting those propeties, and where you did it from? The colors defined in your Resources file would be handy as well.

Added. Thanks in advance for your response.


How can I change the color of the TabbedPage indicator (line) in .NET MAUI (Android)?

You can modify it by setting platform native code. Add the following code in your TabbedPage code behind:
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
        FieldInfo tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo = typeof(TabbedPage).GetField("_tabbedPageManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object tabbedPageManager = tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo?.GetValue(this);
        FieldInfo tabLayoutFieldInfo = tabbedPageManager?.GetType().GetField("_tabLayout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var tablayout = tabLayoutFieldInfo?.GetValue(tabbedPageManager) as Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout;
        if (tablayout != null)
        {
            tablayout.SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
        }
#endif
    }

Use Reflection to get TabbedPageManager(cause it is internal class) and TabLayout. Then call SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor method to set Indicator Color. I set it to black color.

Happy coding :)

The color being picked up is the "dotnet purple", that's comes as default with a new app.
These colors are set in Resources/Themes/Colors.xaml:
<Color x:Key="Primary">#512BD4</Color>
<Color x:Key="PrimaryDark">#ac99ea</Color>
<Color x:Key="PrimaryDarkText">#242424</Color>
<Color x:Key="Secondary">#DFD8F7</Color>
<Color x:Key="SecondaryDarkText">#9880e5</Color>
<Color x:Key="Tertiary">#2B0B98</Color>

And Platforms/Android/resources/values/colors.xml:
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#512BD4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2B0B98</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2B0B98</color>
</resources>

Typically, the tab bar selected color would come as part of the theming for an app, and the defaults are setup as such. Have a play with these colors, and see which one changes the selected color.
It might also be worth a look at the theme setup in Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml. There's one that targets a tabbed page, which defaults as following. . . but might be unrelated to what you're trying to do right now:
 <Style TargetType="TabbedPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Magenta}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="UnselectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

I'm sure you can set the tabbar colors in other ways, however this is a good approach to handling app theming.

Thank you. The only effect on changing the color is through the colorPrimary in Platforms/Android/.../colors.xml. However, when I change this color, it also affects other elements, such as buttons in alerts. Is there a way to create a style that specifically targets only the TabbedPage?

Can you add the setup code from the top of your content page?

Updated. I originally didn't include it in the post because there are no changes. It's simply a new, empty template. The only thing I changed recently was the colorPrimary in Platforms/Android/.... That worked, but it also changed the color of other important components. I’m not sure how else to explain it better. MAUI is sometimes really horrible...:D
